Feedback of "not an answer but a comment" flag
Sometimes, quite a few bad answers are given to questions which, luckily, get flagged and removed. However, the feedback we give is not always that clear.
The feedback we give us as follows:

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

There is also another comment that I often see, which states:

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

I have no idea when I can choose the first or the second message. Moreover, both seem to say exactly the same thing. So, for all clarity: When is either one of them given as an option? 

Because it is still unclear to me after a couple of months, I would like to propose alternate messages that are clearer. The message for comments should more clearly state the fact that it is not an answer: 

This is a comment, not an answer. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. For more information, please refer to this page. - From Review

As for the low-quality message, I would like to see:

This does not provide a clear answer to the question. The answer lacks scientific references or the formatting is of low quality and beyond repair. Please provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker - From Review

This is related to Artem's post about unscientific answers and some redundant flags. 
Edit
I just saw a new message for the first time ever, which approximates what I would like to see. This message was posted after I flagged "low quality formatting or content", but I am not sure whether it is the result of that. 

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation. - From Review


Don't fully know how this works myself.
